# Codeigniter Loading and reading files inside library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a folder inside my library folder called ip_files. example: `library/ip_files/0.php` the ip_files folder contains multiple files. See image:

[image]

I have created a class inside the `ip_files` folder called `GetCountry` the code of the class is as follows:

```
class GetCountry
{

    public function iptocountry($ip)
    {
        $numbers = preg_split("/\./", $ip);
        echo $numbers[0] . ".php"; //test path

        //I have also tried the below for include path
        //include(base_url()."application/libraries/ip_files/".$numbers[0] . ".php"); 
        //gives a forbidden error

        include($numbers[0] . ".php");
        $code = ($numbers[0] * 16777216) + ($numbers[1] * 65536) + ($numbers[2] * 256) + ($numbers[3]);
        foreach ($ranges as $key => $value) {
            if ($key <= $code) {
                if ($ranges[$key][0] >= $code) {
                    $country = $ranges[$key][1];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return $country;
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLERS FOLDER**

```
   public function index($page = 'index')
   {
    $this->load->library('ip_files/GetCountry'); //load library
    $country = $this->getcountry->iptocountry($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); //call function
    var_dump($country);

    $this->load->view('templates/head', $data);
    $this->load->view('users/' . $page, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}
```

**My Problem**

Im getting the error `Message: include(::1.php): failed to open stream: Invalid argument`

Im also getting an undefined offset within the foreach loop because I suspect the path is not being opened correctly for the function to loop over the files.

Any help or advice would be appreciated. (Please keep in mind im new to CodeIgniter)

Comment: Hi didn't you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying in localhost this is why `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` returning `::1`. For getting solid number as your file name first remove this `::` sign from string.

```
$file_name = str_replace("::","",$numbers[0]);
include($file_name . ".php");
```

and for undefined offset issue check with `isset()` function where using offset like

```
if(isset($numbers[0])){
   $file_name = str_replace("::","",$numbers[0]);
}
```

and

```
if(isset($ranges[$key][0])){
    if ($ranges[$key][0] >= $code) {
        $country = $ranges[$key][1];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem it took me 4-hours to figure out it is the localhost causing the problem UGH.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the `$ip` variable contains IPv6 loopback address, usually expressed as `::1`, therefore you could apply an IPv4 only filter using `FILTER_VALIDATE_IP` with `FILTER_FLAG_IPV4` flag :

```
class GetCountry
{

    public function iptocountry($ip)
    {
        if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4)) {
            $numbers = preg_split("/\./", $ip);
            echo $numbers[0] . ".php"; //test path

            //I have also tried the below for include path
            //include(base_url()."application/libraries/ip_files/".$numbers[0] . ".php"); 
            //gives a forbidden error

            include($numbers[0] . ".php");
            $code = ($numbers[0] * 16777216) + ($numbers[1] * 65536) + ($numbers[2] * 256) + ($numbers[3]);
            foreach ($ranges as $key => $value) {
                if ($key <= $code) {
                    if ($ranges[$key][0] >= $code) {
                        $country = $ranges[$key][1];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return $country;
        }
    }
}
```